# Normalize a deeply nested json file in pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to normalize it using json_normalize in Pandas DataFrame. But I couldn't normalize multiple record_path, and it's giving me an error then I tried to normalize just one record_path then it worked. I tried to normalize each element that I needed, but I think there is a way to make the code more efficient. Instead of doing it one by one then concatenate it. This is the code I am using.:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('PZZA.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# normalize the data
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['chart', 'result'], errors='ignore')

# normalize nested data again
df_nested = pd.json_normalize(
    df1['indicators.quote'][0],
    record_path=['open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'volume'],
    record_prefix='quote_'
)
```

I was trying to normalize a json file, but it's giving me an error which is
`TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`. I can't do multiple record_path. But then I tried doing this one by one LOL. Is there any way for me to this efficiently instead of doing this in multiple line of codes? Thanks!

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['chart', 'result'], errors = 'ignore')

df2 = pd.json_normalize(df1['indicators.quote'][0], record_path=['open'])
df3 = pd.json_normalize(df1['indicators.quote'][0], record_path=['close'])
df4 = pd.json_normalize(df1['indicators.quote'][0], record_path=['high'])
df5 = pd.json_normalize(df1['indicators.quote'][0], record_path=['low'])
df6 = pd.json_normalize(df1['indicators.quote'][0], record_path=['volume'])
```

sample code from json file
When you normalize the record path of 'result':

```
{'result': [{'meta': {'currency': 'USD',
    'symbol': 'PZZA',
    'exchangeName': 'NMS',
    'instrumentType': 'EQUITY',
    'firstTradeDate': 739546200,
    'regularMarketTime': 1626120001,
    'gmtoffset': -14400,
    'timezone': 'EDT',
    'exchangeTimezoneName': 'America/New_York',
    'regularMarketPrice': 110.1,
    'chartPreviousClose': 1.944,
    'priceHint': 2,
    'currentTradingPeriod': {'pre': {'timezone': 'EDT',
      'start': 1626076800,
      'end': 1626096600,
      'gmtoffset': -14400},
     'regular': {'timezone': 'EDT',
      'start': 1626096600,
      'end': 1626120000,
      'gmtoffset': -14400},
     'post': {'timezone': 'EDT',
      'start': 1626120000,
```

then the code which I'm planning to extract the column 'indicators.quote'

```
'indicators': {'quote': [{'close': [1.9444444179534912,
       2.194444417953491,
       2.1111111640930176,
       2.25,
       2.3333332538604736,
       2.2083332538604736,
       2.305555582046509,
       2.305555582046509,
       2.25,
       2.25,
       2.222222328186035,
```

So this is the sample of the code that gives me an error

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df1['indicators.quote'][0], record_path=['open', 'close'])
```

and this is the error in Pandas

```
  397             result = result[field]
    398     else:
--> 399         result = result[spec]
    400 except KeyError as e:
    401     if extract_record:

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: could you please give us sample data that can be used to reproduce the error?

Comment: @MuhammadNizami oh I edit my question, please have a look. Thanks!